# Change menu option dynamically according to condition.

Tags: android, eclipse, if-statement, menu

How do I let the `menu layout`and function change if on another `java class`?
I am kinda new to this so i only know about the different screens and some code, but not much..

So i would like the `menu layout` to change after I commanded that.

For example: `layout` is Fullscreen, options and quit. When I click on fullscreen, I want the menu to change so that it now looks like: Exit Fullscreen, options, quit.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can keep your state with some booleans or any other variables you want. 
Then check these in [onPrepareOptionsMenu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onPrepareOptionsMenu%28android.view.Menu%29) and inflate the correct menu.

Comment: Could you give me some example code? as I said i dont know really much yet, not sure how to implent that optionsmenu